# Proof in "New Multi-Signatures in the Plain Public-key Model and a General Forking lemma"

Tags: multi-signature

Reading [here](http://soc1024.ece.illinois.edu/teaching/ece498am/fall2017/forkinglemma.pdf),I was confused in the proof of "A Multi-Signature Scheme based on Discrete Logarithms" proposed by authors.I felt strange to the technique(using array $T_0[]$、$T_1[]$、$T_2[]$ and state $alert$、$bad$)，can someone give me a straightforward explain of this proof(or some similar proofs of other schemes)?

Comment: This seems to differ from this version: http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/multisignatures-ccs.pdf maybe reading it may help?

Comment: That is full verson of the version you referenced, so this is the same